# I am setting a cookie's expiration time 10 mins which is working fine in local system but on server, it's not working

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am setting a cookie's expiration time 10 mins which is working fine in local system but on server, it's not working.

Comment: its not working at all ? or its not keep 10min ? If its not working at all check the cookies settings on web.config and make sure for the correct domain value

Comment: Can you show relevant parts of your code? Are you setting the cookie manually? web.config?

Answer (score 0):

have u check global IIS setting?
if u set your app to be more than global setting, then the setting will not effect.

Comment: I have checked global IIS setting which is fine, Can you tel me some other solution.Vinay

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this [ASP.NET cookie expiration time is always 1/1/0001 12:00 AM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/198295/asp-net-cookie-expiration-time-is-always-1-1-0001-1200-am)