# Do cookies have the equivalent of a primary key?

Tags: asp.net, cookies, webforms

Coming from a non-web background I'm struggling with cookie uniqueness. When I read and write to a cookie named CustomerCode I find multiple cookies with the same name in my cookie collection(s). How can this be avoided?

[image: duplicate request cookies]

[image: duplicate response cookies]

Database rows use a primary key to ensure uniqueness. Is there an equivalent for cookies? I'm using this ["Reusable Cookie Container" code](http://chwe.at/blog/post/2009/01/28/Testable-and-reusable-cookie-access-with-ASPNet-MVC-RC.aspx) to simplify writing to a cookie:

```
Master.Cookies.CustomerCode = SessionWrapper.CustomerCode;
```

Then in my SessionWrapper I restore session variables from the cookie(s)

```
public static void InitiateSessionVariablesFromCookies(IAppCookies appCookies) {
    if (SessionWrapper.CustomerCode == null && appCookies.CustomerCode != null) {
        SessionWrapper.CustomerCode = appCookies.CustomerCode;
    }...
```

**The cookie collection contains CustomerCode multiple times so the wrong value is being passed to the session variable.** If this question is difficult to answer without seeing all of my code please describe the proper / best way to set cookies and then read them back into session variables (or include a link to help me out).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have different expiration date/times you can get "duplicates".

```
HttpCookie Temp = new HttpCookie("MyName", "123");
Temp.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(5);

Response.Cookies.Add(Temp);
```

This code will create a new cookie each time it runs with the same name and value.

Comment: I believe that solves my problem. I had been setting Expires to DateTime.Now.AddDays(10) and the time portion was different each time causing "duplicate" cookies. I've changed setting Expires to DateTime.Today.AddDays(10). I have meetings now but will mark this as the answer later if that worked. Thanks!

Comment: Here's a nicely written article on ASP.NET Cookies which details potential problems and how to work around them: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3106/On-The-Care-and-Handling-of-Cookies. I landed on it after reading this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/198295/asp-net-cookie-expiration-time-is-always-1-1-0001-1200-am